# I have a problem with built-in class painting.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-image

Here is the code in **painting.dart** class and in **paintExtendedImage** that causes the erorr:

```
final ImageTilingInfo info =
    createTilingInfo(repeat, rect, destinationRect, sourceRect);
    final ImageShader shader = ImageShader(
    image, info.tmx, info.tmy, info.transform.storage,
    filterQuality: filterQuality);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint..shader = shader);
```

Errors:

> Error: 'ImageTilingInfo' isn't a type. final ImageTilingInfo info =
> Error: Method not found: 'createTilingInfo'. createTilingInfo(repeat,
> rect, destinationRect, sourceRect);

Anyone to help how to solve these errors

tried chatgpt and other alternatives but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, this is how i fixed it. This is a temporary fix in the local code after getting dependencies.

1. Go to the following path inside dependencies: transitive dependencies > extended_image > lib > src > image > painting.dart
2. Import a file at the beginning of the file.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
```

3. Remove the following line

```dart
final ImageTilingInfo info =
    createTilingInfo(repeat, rect, destinationRect, sourceRect);
```

4. And replace the `info.tmx` with `TileMode.clamp` or any value of the Enum `TileMode`. Same with `info.tmy`.
5. Replace `info.transform.storage` with `Float64List(0)`.

Note: To use `Float64List(0)` you'll need to import the file mentioned in 2.